# Why am I getting an error saying that my string is not an iterable?

Tags: javascript, string, iterable

I have a group of small functions which work together to convert a given string from underscore_case to camelCase. Here is a snippet with my code:

```js
function splitStr(str) {
  return str.split('_');
}

function checkStrPosZero(strArr, str) {
  return !strArr.indexOf(str);
}

function editStrIfFalse(zero, str) {
  if (zero) return str;
  let returnStr = '';
  for (const char of str)
    if (checkStrPosZero(str, char)) returnStr += char.toUpperCase();
    else returnStr += char;
  return returnStr;
}

function loopStrArrAndCamelify(str) {
  let returnStr = '';
  for (const char of splitStr(str))
    returnStr += editStrIfFalse(checkStrPosZero(splitStr(str), char));
  return returnStr;
}

console.log(loopStrArrAndCamelify('hello_world'));
```

For some reason, I get an error saying that the `str` variable isn't an iterable, which doesn't make sense, as `str` is a string. Very confused, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `str` is undefined. You're calling `editStrIfFalse()` with only one argument.

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling `editStrIfFalse()` anyway if you already know it's going to just return the string (`zero` is true).

Comment: @isherwood that may be true, but what if ```zero``` is false?

Comment: Your code seems unnecessarily overcomplicated. You don't need to loop over all the characters checking if the index is 0. Just use `str[0]` to get the first character, and `str.substring(1)` to get the rest.

Comment: as @Barmar said, you're calling `editStrIfFalse()` without passing it the second parameter `str`. You can do yourself a favour using more clear variable names, which let you debug your code easily: https://jsfiddle.net/5wdmxu0p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the second argument to `editStrIfFalse()`. So `str` defaults to `undefined`, which is not iterable.

```js
function splitStr(str) {
  return str.split('_');
}

function checkStrPosZero(strArr, str) {
  return !strArr.indexOf(str);
}

function editStrIfFalse(zero, str) {
  if (zero) return str;
  let returnStr = '';
  for (const char of str)
    if (checkStrPosZero(str, char)) returnStr += char.toUpperCase();
    else returnStr += char;
  return returnStr;
}

function loopStrArrAndCamelify(str) {
  let returnStr = '';
  for (const char of splitStr(str))
    returnStr += editStrIfFalse(checkStrPosZero(splitStr(str), char), char);
  return returnStr;
}

console.log(loopStrArrAndCamelify('hello_world'));
```

Note that your algorithm won't work if the first word is repeated later. `strArr.indexOf(str)` will return the index of the first match of `str`, not the current index of the iteration, which will be `0` when you're processing a repeat of the first word. So for example, if the input is `hello_world_hello`, the result will be `helloWorldhello` rather than `helloWorldHello`.

Also, if the first letter of a word is repeated, you have the same problem -- it will convert all the repeats to uppercase. So `hello_wow` becomes `helloWoW`.

If you're going to iterate, you should iterate over the indexes, not the values, then you can test if `index == 0`. But there's no need for most of the iteration. To convert a word to camelcase, just do:

```
new_word = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

And when you're iterating over the words, use `for (let index = 1; index < words.length; index++)` to process just the words after the first.